# Passing data to components in slots

Tags: openlayers-3, vuejs2

Background: I'd like to create a Vue.js wrapper for openlayers. I had in mind that the API can be used like this:

```
<mv-map :center="..." :zoom="..." :projection="...">
  <mv-layer ...>
    <mv-source ...>
      ...
    </mv-source>
  </mv-layer>
</mv-map>
```

I'd love to keep this kind of open interface, as layers can potentially be nested.

My problem is that I create an `ol.Map` object in the `mv-map` component that I somehow have to access in the `mv-layer` component, but I cannot pass it there, because `mv-layer` is added to the slot.

I tried to use `this.$parent.$get(...)` in `mv-layer` but that somehow "is not a function".

How to I either pass down data from parent components to slotted components or access parent data in slotted components?

Comment: You should be able to pass that as props.

Comment: @Saurabh how do I do this? The map object is created within `mv-map`, but the subcomponents are not created there, but from "outside". Or is there a way to pass props to components in a slot?

Comment: Are you able to create a minimal fiddle?

Comment: Any feedback...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.$parent.<property>`.

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/aJJjBy?editors=1010).